# How to hide Y-axis values in invientcharts

Tags: charts, vaadin

Is there a way to hide a InvientChart NumberYAxis? The yaxis is meaningless on logic analyzer display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about hiding simply with a method, but this should work.

```
InvientChartsConfig.YAxisDataLabel label = new InvientChartsConfig.YAxisDataLabel(true);
label.setFormatterJsFunc("function() { return ''; }");
yaxis.setLabel(label);
```

It should replace the numeric values with empty space.

Answer (score 1):

@miq, sorry for late reply, I don't know whether that works. But after serious struggling, I did this..

```
YAxisDataLabel yLabel=new YAxisDataLabel();
yLabel.setEnabled(false);
yAxis.setLabel(yLabel);
```

And its working like charm...anyways thanks for your answer. I will consider that and will try it int future..